# Whether this piece of code is thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written the following code

```
 public class ClassA
 {
    private ClassB classBObj;
    private ClassA classAObj = new ClassA();
    public classA()
    {
           if(classBObj == null)
           {
               classBObj = new ClassB();
           }
    }
     //getter method for classbObj
  }
```

I want to use other classes such as SolrQuery, SolrServer in Solrj. If I define those classes as classBObj , will it be always thread safe?

And Whether classAObj is threadsafe?

I don't understand this part. Please give me some suggestions and I want to know how to test whether a piece of code is thread-safe in the future by myself alone. How to do that?

Assume, I am going to use classBObj in other classes as `classA.getInstance().getclassBObj()`. `getInstance just returns classAObj`.

Comment: do you want double locking singleton pattern?

Comment: Um, the initialization code for a ClassA instance unconditionally creates _another_ ClassA instance?  How does that not crash your program?

Answer (score 0):

The general question of testing if a piece of code is thread-safe is a difficult problem, one in which you should test all possibles execution paths in a multi-thread scenario.

That said there are a variety of techniques or patterns to ensure that a piece of code is thread safe. That is ensuring that the fields of an object or class always maintain a valid state, as observed by other objects and classes, even when used concurrently by multiple threads.

The most common techniques include:

- Identify and [synchronize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) critical sections
- Make your data immutable
- Use a thread-safe wrapper

Constructor (like in your case) cannot be marked synchronized ([spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#8.8.3)). Most of the time it's not a problem constructors because other threads generally cannot see the object being created until the thread creating it has finished it.  In some contrived case (for example if you give out your object being constructed - not a great idea) you can still use a synchronized-block.